# @aws-sdk/client-s3 --> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, digital-ocean-spaces, aws-sdk-js-v3

I'm trying to upload from localhost to digital ocean's space .

For this, I use the npm package.
But I am getting the error given below. What code should I add to this package so that I don't get an error.

Access to fetch at 'https://****.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/directory/aaa.txt?x-id=PutObject' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

My codes:

const handleFileUpload = async file => {

const bucketParams = {
Bucket: "bucketname",
Key: "directory/aaa.txt",
ACL: "public-read",
Body: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

};

const command = new AbortMultipartUploadCommand(bucketParams);

```
try {
  
  const data = await s3Client
  .send(new PutObjectCommand(bucketParams));
  

} catch (error) {
  // error handling.
  
} finally {
  // finally.
}
```

};

/// Connection code

import { S3 } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";

export const s3Client = new S3({
endpoint: "https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com",
region: "us-east-1",
credentials: {
accessKeyId: "xxxxxx",
secretAccessKey: "xxxx",
}
})
;

Comment: Dupe (with answer)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796264/uploading-file-to-digitalocean-spaces-get-access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-url-fr